# How to derive the commutation relation of $[\textbf{L}\cdot \textbf{S},L_z]$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to derive the commutation relation of $[\textbf{L}\cdot \textbf{S},L_z]$. I know that $[L_zS_z,J_z]=0$, so we get;

$$[\textbf{L}\cdot \textbf{S},L_z]=[L_xS_x+L_yS_y,L_z]=[L_xS_x,L_z]+[L_yS_y,L_z]=L_x[S_x,L_z]+[L_x,L_z]S_x+L_y[S_y,L_x]+[L_y,L_z]S_y$$

Now using the commutation relation of $[L_x,L_z]$ and $[L_y,L_z]$, we get:

$$[\textbf{L}\cdot \textbf{S},L_z]=-i\hbar L_yS_x+i\hbar L_xS_y+L_x[S_x,L_z]+L_y[S_y,L_x]$$

The solutions simply write: $$[\textbf{L}\cdot \textbf{S},L_z]=S_x[L_x,L_z]+S_y[L_y,L_z]=-iS_xL_y+iS_yL_x$$

But how do they arrive at the expression after the first equality sign?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that the spin operators $\textbf{S}$ and $\textbf{J}$ are defined on two different vector spaces that are (assumably) completely independent of each other and must commute. Then we have;

$$[L_i,S_j]=0, \; i,j \in {1,2,3}/x,y,z$$